# jQuery toggle next P

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to create a function that will toggle a paragraphs display CSS when a button is clicked only i cant seem to get it to work at all, My browser just goes back to the top of the page? My jQuery is...

```
$('.useful-links ul li a').click(function(){
    $('.useful-links ul li a').parent('li').find('p').toggle();     
});
```

and my markup is

```
<li>
     <a href="#">RESIDENTIAL AGENTS</a>
     <p style="display:none;">sfsdfsdfsd</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your HTML structure is like this:

```
<div class="useful-links">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">RESIDENTIAL AGENTS</a>
            <p style="display:none;">sfsdfsdfsd</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>​

// For your jQuery selector to work as you have it

$('.useful-links ul li a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop href()
    $(this).next('p').toggle();     
});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/p4SJB/

Comment: Is your HTML structured correctly? Also as everyone else is saying `e.preventDefault();` might be the issue

Comment: It's always the craziest thing, anytime

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)`:

```
$('.useful-links ul li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('li').find('p').toggle();     
});
```

I prefer to find the common parent, then "find" the target element. This means that if your HTML markup changes so that `p` comes before `a`, your jQuery won't be affected.

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S2hSp/

Comment: @Liam Your example doesn't include a `useful-links` element so its not going to select the right elements.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you are working with an anchor element so you need to prevent the default action. Then you can do your logic:

```
$('.useful-links ul li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').find('p').toggle();     
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/TbVN2/)

---

also, if you know your `a` and `p` elements will always have the same parents you can use the `siblings` method (not really to any better effect, just an alternate):

```
$(this).siblings('p').toggle();
```

[and another example](http://jsfiddle.net/TbVN2/1/)